# Comma and newline replaced with comma

Tags: shell-script

How can I find the solution to replace ":" and newline with comma, and to remove "./" below is the sample format.

```
ls -lRm

./www.toncemoy.com:
www_ttoncemly_com, www_ttoncely_com, www_toncethly_com, www_tncemhly_com
```

In above output I wants to remove "./" and ": newline" with comma, sample is as follows:

```
www.toncemoy.com, www_ttoncemly_com, www_ttoncely_com, www_toncethly_com, www_tncemhly_com
```

Comment: Why parse the output from `ls`. Have you thought about directory names with newlines? That output you show could actually be of one file in the current directory. Do you want to mangle those as well? What if a filename includes a comma & space (as is valid)? If you want some comma separated list of files per directory, you need to think about how to handle non-trivial file names.

Comment: Please don't repost the same question. Your previous question was closed as unclear. Edit it to make it clear and it will be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not filter the output of `ls`

```
for dir in */; do printf "%s, " "$dir"; ls -m "$dir"; echo; done
```

will give you the output you want.

Comment: Thanks.... This worked perfectly on console however if i am putting the output to a file then single line is breaking in 2-3 lines. Could please let me know why ?

Comment: show exactly what you're doing

Comment: I am doing like below:

for dir in */; do printf "%s, " "$dir"; ls -m "$dir"; echo; done > output.txt

cat output.txt
activestop.nicorette.com.ar/, prod-activestop_nicorette_com_ar.crt, prod-activestop_nicorette_com_ar.csr,
prod-activestop_nicorette_com_ar.intermediate.ca.crt,
prod-activestop_nicorette_com_ar.key

Comment: formatting is lost in comments. Looks OK to me. What does `wc -l output.txt` tell you?

Comment: Output is :  3 output.txt

Comment: how many directories are there? the for loop will give you one line for each directory.

Comment: There are 23 Directories. Yes on console it is giving one line for each directory but when i m redirecting the output to a file all lines are breaking in 2-3 lines.

Comment: Bizarre. Could you have filenames with newlines in them?

Comment: wait. there are 23 directories, but your output file has only 3 lines?

Comment: I checked on one directory that's why only 3 lines.. but actual count of directories is 23.

Comment: Hi, can you please suggest further..

Comment: not really. there's no reason why your file would get extra newlines unless they are present in the filenames.